# React Navigation - cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I've been trying to get up and running with [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/) but I run into a problem when I try to move navigation items into their own components.

HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

import NavButton from '../components/NavButton'

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
        Hello World
        </Text>

        <NavButton
        navigate={this.props.navigator}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});


export default HomeScreen;
```

Then in the NavButton component I try to navigate to the new screen.

```
 class NavButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
        title="Go to About"
        onPress={() => this.props.navigator.navigate('About')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default NavButton;
```

But I keep getting the error "Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined.

Here is my Router.js file as well.

```
import React from 'react';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen'
import AboutScreen from '../screens/AboutScreen'


export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  About: {
    screen: AboutScreen
  }
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you rename `navigate={this.props.navigator}` to `navigator={this.props.navigation}`, it should work because in NavButton you are calling `this.props.navigator.navigate`.

Comment: It is still coming up with an error on the onPress function on the navButton.

Comment: Oh i think its supposed to be `this.props.navigation` not `this.props.navigator`

Comment: Figured it out! The correct word to use is navigation={this.props.navigation}.

Comment: How to use navigator={this.props.navigation}?

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function GoToButton() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title='Screen Name'
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate(screenName)}
    />
  );
}
```

You can use useNavigation from @react-navigation/native with React Navigation v 5.x.
More details in the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/).

Answer (score 0):

An ordinary component that is not a screen component will not receive the navigation prop by default.

To resolve this exception, you could pass the navigation prop in to NavButton when you render it from a screen, like so: `<NavButton navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

Alternatively, we can use the `withNavigation` function to provide the navigation prop automatically

```js
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class NavButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Back"
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.navigation.goBack();
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

// withNavigation returns a component that wraps NavButton and passes in the
// navigation prop
export default withNavigation(NavButton);
```

refer: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are compiling ES6

if not simply use this.props.navigation 
or 
this.props.navigation.navigate
whatever you need