# Cannot read property 'navigate' of Undefined in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-router

i'm React Native newbie. What i'm trying to do is added [react navigation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) to my login page where user can click a button and navigate to the sign up page but i'm getting an error `Cannot read property 'navigate' of Undefined`. I've already searched the solution over an internet but no luck. This So does not help me - [React Navigation - cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793844/react-navigation-cannot-read-property-navigate-of-undefined) and same with others .

Here is my code

**index.ios.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './src/screens/Login';
import Signup from './src/screens/Signup';

export default class tapak extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.buttonPress = this.buttonPress.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{color: 'blue'}} onPress={this.buttonPress}>sign up</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  buttonPress() {
    console.log('called');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup');
  }
}

const Stacks = StackNavigator({
    Login: {
      screen: Login
    },
    Signup:{
      screen: Signup
    }
});
```

Comment: Where are you using "tapak"? It doesn't look like its in your Stack

Comment: I'm not using it anywhere. This is my index.ios.js file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Render the StackNavigator in your **index.ios.js** and move the button to the **Login** component:

```
const Stacks = StackNavigator({
    Login: {
      screen: Login
    },
    Signup:{
      screen: Signup
    }
});

class tapak extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Stacks />
    );
  }
}
```

**Login.js :**

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.buttonPress = this.buttonPress.bind(this);
  }

  buttonPress() {
    console.log('called');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{color: 'blue'}} onPress={this.buttonPress}>sign up</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Working example 
[here](https://snack.expo.io/HkXlNv0WZ).

Answer (score 2):

Write this code to index.ios.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './src/screens/Login';
import Signup from './src/screens/Signup';

const Stacks = StackNavigator({
    Login: {
      screen: Login
    },
    Signup:{
      screen: Signup
    }
});
```

Login.js

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
import {
  Text, View , Button,Image,
} from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text
          onPress={() => navigate('Signup')}
        > SignUp</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. It's not working, same error. Hmm

Comment: try this : onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup')}

Comment: remove constructor from component

Comment: remove export default class tapak extends Component { } because your index.ios.js file display stack

Comment: Does that mean my index.ios must be in the Stacks in order for it to working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145630/discussion-between-nidhi-patel-and-digit).

Comment: It helped for me !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include `navigationOptions`, for example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Great',
    // other configurations
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // your view
    )
  }
}
```

Also yu need to make sure you use `AppRegistry.registerComponent('glfm', () => Stacks);` rather than `AppRegistry.registerComponent('glfm', () => tapak);`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. It's not working, same error :-(.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer to this question is to just put const { navigate } = this.props.navigation in your render() function and then you can use it in any component that you need

For Example

```
render() {
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
 return (
  <View>
    <Text>This is the home screen of the app</Text>
    <Button
      onPress={() => navigate('Profile', { name: 'Brent' })}
      title="Go to Brent's profile"
    />
  </View>
);
}
```

Please read this doc for https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, we must know that stack.navigator provides a default prop called 'navigation' to it's children. So, make sure you provide that default prop as a prop to further children as well. Now the function navigation will not be undefined.